# moving a UIImageView around a circumference?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, rotation, geometry

I am currently developing a game for the iphone in which many images will spin around circles. I have struck the point in which I must write the code to achieve this. I am confused by what mathematical operations I must use and how I would implement this. It would help tremendously if the process could be explained, using code examples. If anyone is confused by what I mean, I am simply trying to move the center of a UIImageView around the circumference of a circle at a constand speed. Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CGRect rect1;
CGRect rect2;
CGRect rect3;....`

in viewdidload()
{

```
rect1 = imageView1.frame
rect2 = imageView2.frame;
rect3 = imageView3.frame;



[UIImageView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];




[UIImageView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIImageView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIImageView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
[UIImageView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(rotate:)];

imageView1.center = CGPointMake(rect2.origin.x, rect2.origin.y);
imageView1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2);
imageView2.center = CGPointMake(rect3.origin.x, rect3.origin.y);
imageView2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
    [UIImageView commitAnimations];
     }

- (void)rotate:(NSString *)animationID
   {
[UIImageView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIImageView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIImageView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIImageView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
[UIImageView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(rotate1:)];

imageView1.center = CGPointMake(rect3.origin.x, rect3.origin.y);
imageView1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
imageView1.alpha = 1;
imageView2.center = CGPointMake(rect4.origin.x, rect4.origin.y);
imageView2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2);
imageView2.alpha = .5;
    .....
   [UIImageView commitAnimations];
     }

     - (void)rotate1:(NSString *)animationID
    {
[UIImageView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIImageView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIImageView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIImageView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
[UIImageView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(rotate2:)];

imageView1.center = CGPointMake(rect4.origin.x, rect4.origin.y);
imageView1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2);
imageView1.alpha = .5;
imageView2.center = CGPointMake(rect5.origin.x, rect5.origin.y);
imageView2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
imageView2.alpha = .15;
     ....
    [UIImageView commitAnimations];
      }

     try like this
```